# Cannot create a batch file containing this script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I am trying to create a batch file that runs the following commands and its not working so i would appreciate any kind of help guys.
the batch file should run a utility and access a folder and get files from the folder.
here is the script:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
winscp.com /command ^
"open sftp://user:password@link/" ^
"cd folder" ^
"option transfer binary" ^
"get *.txt d:\destination" ^
"close"
```

Comment: Add a space at the start of each line which begins with a quote `"`, that avoids problems with the multiline caret `^`. Btw. `its not working` isn't a useful description

Comment: Execute line by line to check each step. Which step is failing ?

Comment: Why do you not just put all the commands in a script file?

Comment: may be you can download and use `pscp.exe` to do the same in simple way. Usage - `pscp.exe remoteUser@remotehost:/absolute/filepath /local/machine/path/where/to/getit`

Comment: Thank you guys 
@jeb seems like the space was the problem